# Lost all permissions for desktop

Tags: permissions

so recently, I lost all permissions for my desktop. I can no longer save there, move files/folders there, etc. All I can do is read & execute. Is there any way I can get those back? The security tab says I should have full control. I am using Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users\%User% (%User% being your username, for example, my would be Samuel) and right click the "Desktop" folder. Go to "Properties". Then click on the "Security" tab, third from the left. From there click the "Edit..." Box. Then click your Username and make sure "Full control" is checked in the box below. If you do not see your name you will have to click the "Add..." box and add your username to the list, remembering to give yourself full control.

If that doesn't work you can always take ownership from a command shell. Rather than typing out a bunch of commands someone was kind to give us a program to run that add that exact Functionality to the right click menu. (Link Below) All you have to do is navigate to the same C:\Users\%User% folder and right click "Desktop" and click "Take Ownership" (after you've ran the program downloaded at the link)

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/